# RestKit not working when used in a static library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

I am wanting to write a static library which uses `RestKit`, for an iOS application -- but the `RestKit` calls are not working in the static library's unit tests.

I'm almost certain that I'm doing something completely silly here, but I cannot figure out what this is.

Using the static library in an iOS application, and running it in the iOS Simulator, works as desired.

Is there something that needs to be done to get `RestKit` to work in a static library as opposed to in an iOS application?

I've created a sample Xcode 4 project [here](https://github.com/dbarros/RestKitStaticLibraryTest).

The code calling my API is simple:

```
+ (void)testRestKit
{ 
    NSString* URL = @"http://0.0.0.0:3000/api";
    RKClient* client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:URL username:@"me@somewhere.com" password:@"password"];
    [client get:@"/users/current" delegate:nil];
}
```

My test is just:

```
- (void)testExample
{
    [MyLib testRestKit];
    sleep(10);
}
```

*Note:* I added the sleep just in case it was a timing thing, where the unit tests would finish without `RestKit` being given a chance to complete the API call. It did not help.

Even though the `RestKit` call does not work, there are no visible errors either.

**Update:** For those interested in doing something similar, you may also want to check out Daniel Jalkut's [RSTestingKit](https://github.com/danielpunkass/RSTestingKit). Essentially they are classes that provide, among a few other things, what the solution provided here does.

Comment: How do you know it's not working if you're not setting up a delegate to get the callbacks?

Comment: Even without the delegate I can see if the REST API is called on my Rails app, which provides the API.

Comment: Got it. (About a minute after I left that comment, I realized what the answer would probably be.)

Comment: I wondered if it could have something to do with the requiring something that a UI application has? An event loop? Application object and delegate? I'm not sure if that's the case.

So I decided to try GHUnit instead of OCUnit. http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/

And this time... it worked!

It leaves me uneasy not knowing why using OCUnit didn't work. But this will have to do for now.

Comment: I just took a glance over the RestKit code, and the lack of run loop could indeed be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping the thread when you're waiting for something to happen isn't likely to help, but you could try cranking the run loop around a few times:

```
- (void)testExample
{
    [MyLib testRestKit];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:25]];
}
```

I haven't really looked into this thoroughly enough to be confident it'll help (or to explain why, if it does), but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. That was it. The call now goes through to RestKit. Switching to GHUnit made me wonder if it was something to do with the event loop -- being an iOS newbie, I wasn't sure how to go about it for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You had asked this question on the Restkit list serve too; I forked your project https://github.com/dbarros/RestKitStaticLibraryTest and fixed it up for you:

The second pull req https://github.com/dbarros/RestKitStaticLibraryTest/pull/2 adds the runloop. Which, looking at the answers here, Josh Caswell and I were thinking alike.

Since Josh already correctly diagnosed the problem with a solution and posted it above, and I had already committed a fix, I'm only mentioning this because of the pull request with the fix.

Comment: Thanks for all your help here and on github, Shane. You guys were right: the NSRunLoop was the fix.